# How to get Eclipse Warnings when compiling with maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Java project using m2eclipse. In my Eclipse, I get several Warnings.

How can I display those warnings in my maven compilation? I want to use warnings-plugin on jenkins to keep track of the number of warnings.

I found [this](http://frequal.com/java/EnableWarningsInMaven.html) post on how to enable warnings in maven, but it only gives me a small subset of warnings.

E.g.

> "The value of ... is not used" warnings don't show up.

How can I get the same warnings as displayed in Eclipse?
Thanks for help :)

Edit for clarity: I would like to display the same warnings as in eclipse, not other bugs as reported by FindBugs, PMD or checkstyle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem, so I wanna share it :)
I added this to my pom-file, and now the warnings show up during compilation with maven, and I was able to include them to jenkins using the warnings plugin.
The important thing I missed in my first attempts was, that the plugins need to be under pluginManagement.

The warnings are generated by a specific compiler, to prevent the error "no such compiler: eclipse" the dependency to the plexus-compiler is included.

Hope this works for others as well :)

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                                <version>1.8.6</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
         </pluginManagement>
   </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better than the eclipse warnings, you could use a static analysis tool like **PMD** and the right rules. Check the [Maven PMD Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/)

Examples of rules you could use:

- [Type Resolution](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/index.html#Type_Resolution)
- [Empty Code](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/index.html#Empty_Code)
- [JavaBeans](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/index.html#http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/index.html#JavaBeans)
- [Unused Code](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/index.html#Unused_Code)

Comment: The reason I would like to use the eclipse warnings is, that it would "force" other developers to only submit warning free code to svn. But I will have a look at PMD as well.